# Timing requirement not met during design compilation

Tags: fpga, clock, timing, intel-fpga, quartus

I have created a design and would like to compile the design in order to create a binary file for the CPLD. However when I try to compile the design, it outputs a warning saying that the timing requirements not met. It seems like it is complaining about the following VHDL component where the external clock is divided into a lower clock frequency that is used by the other VHDL components in the design:

```vhdl
entity clk_divider is
    generic (COUNTER_MAX : integer := 256000);
    port(
            clk_in  : in std_logic;
            reset   : in std_logic;
            clk_out : out std_logic
        );
end clk_divider;    

architecture Behavioral of clk_divider is

    signal signal_level : std_logic := '0';
    signal counter : integer range 0 to COUNTER_MAX := 0;

begin
    clk_divider : process (clk_in, reset)
        begin

        if (reset = '1') then
            signal_level <= '0';
            counter <= 0;
        elsif rising_edge(clk_in) then
            if (counter = COUNTER_MAX) then
                signal_level <= not(signal_level);
                counter <= 0;
            else
                counter <= counter + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    clk_out <= signal_level;
end Behavioral;
```

The critical warning message shown during design compilation is shown below:

```
Critical Warning (332012): Synopsys Design Constraints File file not found: 'monitor.sdc'. 
A Synopsys Design Constraints File is required by the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer to get proper timing constraints. 
Without it, the Compiler will not properly optimize the design.
Info (332142): No user constrained base clocks found in the design. Calling "derive_clocks -period 1.0"
Info (332105): Deriving Clocks
    Info (332105): create_clock -period 1.000 -name clk clk
    Info (332105): create_clock -period 1.000 -name clk_divider:clk_module|signal_level clk_divider:clk_module|signal_level
Info: Found TIMEQUEST_REPORT_SCRIPT_INCLUDE_DEFAULT_ANALYSIS = ON
Info: Can't run Report Timing Closure Recommendations. The current device family is not supported.
Critical Warning (332148): Timing requirements not met
Info (332146): Worst-case setup slack is -7.891
    Info (332119):     Slack       End Point TNS Clock 
    Info (332119): ========= =================== =====================
    Info (332119):    -7.891            -123.541 clk 
    Info (332119):    -1.602              -5.110 clk_divider:clk_module|signal_level 
Info (332146): Worst-case hold slack is -0.816
    Info (332119):     Slack       End Point TNS Clock 
    Info (332119): ========= =================== =====================
    Info (332119):    -0.816              -0.816 clk 
    Info (332119):     1.732               0.000 clk_divider:clk_module|signal_level 
Info (332146): Worst-case recovery slack is -4.190
    Info (332119):     Slack       End Point TNS Clock 
    Info (332119): ========= =================== =====================
    Info (332119):    -4.190             -20.950 clk_divider:clk_module|signal_level 
    Info (332119):    -3.654             -76.734 clk 
Info (332146): Worst-case removal slack is 4.320
    Info (332119):     Slack       End Point TNS Clock 
    Info (332119): ========= =================== =====================
    Info (332119):     4.320               0.000 clk 
    Info (332119):     4.856               0.000 clk_divider:clk_module|signal_level 
Info (332146): Worst-case minimum pulse width slack is -2.289
    Info (332119):     Slack       End Point TNS Clock 
    Info (332119): ========= =================== =====================
    Info (332119):    -2.289              -2.289 clk 
    Info (332119):     0.247               0.000 clk_divider:clk_module|signal_level 
Info (332001): The selected device family is not supported by the report_metastability command.
Info (332102): Design is not fully constrained for setup requirements
Info (332102): Design is not fully constrained for hold requirements
```

What is the reason for this warning message and how can I solve it? Also what does the slack numbers say about my design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *monitor.sdc* cannot be found, Quartus tries to synthesize your circuit at 1GHz (period=1ns) as far as the logs reveal the following constraints.

```
create_clock -period 1.000 -name clk clk
create_clock -period 1.000 -name clk_divider:clk_module|signal_level clk_divider:clk_module|signal_level
```

The first line is for `clk` port (it must be in the top-level module/entity) and the second line is for `signal_level` signal. You can modify the periods appropriately and put the constraints into *monitor.sdc*. Then you should add that file to the project.

A slack value tells you the difference between the target and the actual. If a path meets the timing requirement, it has a positive slack. If doesn't meet, the slack is negative.

Your target clock period was 1ns, but you got -7.891ns slack for the critical (worst) path. The actual period achievable can be calculated as follows.

```
actual period = target period - setup slack = 1.000 - (-7.891) = 8.891ns
```

According to the results above, 8.9ns can be an achievable period for `clk`. I would also try smaller values, but there is no need if your real input clock (`clk`) is not faster than 100MHz.

The period of `signal_level` depends on the minimum value of `COUNTER_MAX`. Actually the rest of the circuit already seems faster than `clk_divider` module, because the slack (-1.602) of `signal_level` is better. You can set the same period with `clk`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, it seems like the .sdc was missing. I have added the two lines into my .sdc file and modified the -period parameter. For `clk` I have set to 488.281 (2.048 MHz) and `signal_level` I have set to 1000000000 (1 Hz) since I want to have `clk_divider` as 1 Hz clock. However, I get a warning saying that: _Warning (332049): Ignored create_clock at synopsys-design-constraints.sdc(2): Time value "1000000000" is not valid
Info (332050): create_clock -period 1000000000 -name clk_divider:clk_module|signal_level clk_divider:clk_module|signal_level_ What have I done wrong? Thanks

Comment: @Mrchacha You can try a lesser period (e.g. 10000). In addition, I recommend that you put some margin for the first clock constraint. For example, 20% (~400ns).

Comment: I removed the internal clock signal and modified it to be output a pulse. So it is working correctly now. Why would you recommend to have some margin for the clock constraint?

Comment: @Mrchacha Because the clock signal on hardware is not ideal. Maybe it is a little bit faster, or the duty cycle deviates from 50% etc. 20% margin may sound odd, but it's still a common approach in the industry to be on the safe side.